# Pulling floats to sum data in array structure using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I'm trying to pull numbers from an array structure and then I want to sum them.

Example row entry:

```
{"DBA":50.0},{"RST":132.0},{"ZIT":752}
```

I would want to sum all of the number values so 50 + 132 + 752 = 934

What I have tried: col = column name

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(col, LEN(LEFT(col, CHARINDEX (':', col))) + 1, LEN(col) - LEN(LEFT(col, 
    CHARINDEX (':', col))) - LEN(RIGHT(col, LEN(col) - CHARINDEX ('}', Benefit))) - 1)    
FROM table
```

This works to grab the first value (so 50.0) in the above example, but will not grab each value. Any idea how I can make this query grab multiple values and then sum them together?

Comment: What version of SQL Server? Where is the array structure stored, and isn't it possible to break apart the array _before the app stores it_ and store it relationally?

Comment: @AaronBertrand SQL server 2019. The Array is stored in a column. The purpose is a homework assignment so not looking for optimizing the structure/data flow - just want to query from what I have and then sum for each row

Comment: If you "must" store the data in a non-relational way, then I would at least suggest storing it in well formed JSON (or `xml`) so you can at least parse it easily.

Comment: @Larnu It's a homework assignment so can't change the setup unfortunately

Comment: If it's a homework assignment there is probably a very specific method the instructor expects you to use, so I'm not sure asking a bunch of peers "how would _you_ do it?" will necessarily get you great marks. Are there not course materials leading up to this assignment that might guide you in what the instructor is looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content is almost a valid JSON, so you may try to fix it and parse it with built-in JSON support using `OPENJSON()` (a valid JSON content is `[{"DBA":50.0},{"RST":132.0},{"ZIT":752}]`):

```
SELECT 
  t.[Column],
  [Sum] = (
     SELECT SUM(CONVERT(numeric(10, 1), j2.value)) 
     FROM OPENJSON(CONCAT('[', t.[Column], ']')) j1
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.[value]) j2
  )
FROM (VALUES
   ('{"DBA":50.0},{"RST":132.0},{"ZIT":752}')
) t ([Column])
```

Answer (score 2):

I would, personally, convert your data into actual well formed JSON. Then you can easily `SUM` the values:

```sql
DECLARE @YourString nvarchar(MAX) = N'{"DBA":50.0},{"RST":132.0},{"ZIT":752}';

SELECT SUM(TRY_CONVERT(decimal(5,1),[value]))
FROM (VALUES(CONCAT('{',REPLACE(REPLACE(@YourString,'{',''),'}',''),'}')))V(JSONString)
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(V.JSONString);
```

Or you could add a `WITH` to the `OPENJSON` call and then add (`+`) the values:

```sql
DECLARE @YourString nvarchar(MAX) = N'{"DBA":50.0},{"RST":132.0},{"ZIT":752}';

SELECT OJ.DBA + OJ.RST + OJ.ZIT
FROM (VALUES(CONCAT('{',REPLACE(REPLACE(@YourString,'{',''),'}',''),'}')))V(JSONString)
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(V.JSONString)
                 WITH (DBA decimal(5,1),
                       RST decimal(5,1),
                       ZIT decimal(5,1)) OJ;
```